# How to get a graphviz node's position attribute?

Tags: python, graphviz

I'm making a graphviz graph in python, not loading it from a file. All I want to do is have a bunch of nodes arranged by neato, and get the position of each node. However, I can't seem to get the position attribute of the nodes; what's the right way to do this?

```
import graphviz

def main():
    dot = graphviz.Graph()
    dot.engine = 'neato'
    node_a = dot.node('A', 'Node A')
    node_b = dot.node('B', 'Node B')
    dot.edge('A', 'B')
    dot.edge('B', 'A')
    dot.render('graph', view=True)

    # Neither of these work:
    dot.getv(node_a, 'pos')
    node_a.node_attr['pos']
```

I know `pos` is a valid attribute of nodes, but how do I even get to see it?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
It produces a file named *myGraph.dot* that cantains **pos** values for all objects and can be used as input to `neato -n2 -Tpng myGraph.dot >myGraph.png`

```
import graphviz

dot = graphviz.Graph(format='dot')
dot.engine = 'neato'
node_a = dot.node('A', 'Node A')
node_b = dot.node('B', 'Node B')
dot.edge('A', 'B')
dot.edge('B', 'A')
dot.render('myGraph')
```

Comment: Not quite; I don't need an external file, or to render the image. I just want the node's positions within the script so I can use them for other purposes.